# Не работает Angular.js при рендере странницы c Flask

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flask

Я формирую страницу с помощью шаблонизатора jinja2 и отдаю следующим образом:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

angular и мой js код подключены следующим образом:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='drqApp'>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js">            </script>
<script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
...
...
</body>
```

Но angular приложение в этом случае не работает, страница рендерится но angular не работает. Если же отдавать `index.html` как файл см.код ниже , то angular работает как надо.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return send_file('index.html')
```

Что я делаю не так? Есть ли возможность подключать angular к динамическим формируемым из шаблонов страницам?

Comment: Без разницы, чем у тебя формируется HTML на сервере (python, ruby, java, js или php). Смотри что у тебя приходит в браузер. Пока мало данных, что бы понять причину.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С вероятностью в 90% уверен что проблема в `{{}}` использумых как ангуляром так и jinja2. К примеру если написать в шаблоне `<input value="{{model_in_scope}}"/>` и если в контексте нет model_in_scope (а в примере его нет), то до клиента дойдет `<input value=""/>` и никакого байндинга не будет. решается это несколькими способами:

1. В лоб: `{% raw %} <input value="{{model_in_scope}}"/> {% endraw %}` - `raw` экранирует текст от компиляции шаблонизатором jinja
2. Заставить использовать angular другие символы для выражения например `{[]}`

   ```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

   app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
   $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[');
   $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}');
   }]);
   ```
3. Заставить jinja использовать `{{[]}}` вместо `{{}}`

   ```
   class CustomFlask(Flask):
      jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy()
      jinja_options.update(dict(              
         variable_start_string='{[',
         variable_end_string='}]',
       ))

   app = CustomFlask(__name__)
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, вы были правы. Конфликт был в `{{}}`